# Integration test a camel-spring-boot route

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a camel-spring-boot application with a couple of routes.
I now want to integration test one of the routes.

This is giving me problems. If I in my test initialize the spring boot application, all the routes are automatically loaded. Properties are read properly from my .yml file.

If I bypass the spring boot application and just use a plain unit test framework to avoid loading all the routes the property loading does not work (properties are not initialized at all and I get an error message).

I think the examples on the camel documentation pages and also the code sample leaves a lot to be desired. I am about to ditch camel-spring-boot altogether, I have spent the whole day on trying to get this to work.

How can I create an integration test for one of many routes with working property loading from a .yml file?

Comment: Could you pls provide the test class

Answer (score 1):

I know this is over a year old. But I ran into this question today myself. Currently using Spring boot 1.4.2 and the apache camel starter 2.18.0. I solved it with the help of `@ClassRule` and `@BeforeClass` so that I can generate a temporary folder and then store that information within the system properties.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("unittest")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AceBatchProcessorIntegrationTests
{
    @ClassRule
    public static final TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws IOException
    {
        folder.create();
        System.setProperty("ace.batch.from", "file:" + folder.getRoot().getPath() + "?include=.*.tcbatch");
        System.setProperty("ace.batch.to", "file:" + folder.getRoot().getPath() + File.pathSeparator + "done");
    }
}
```